Compose: Triggering Navigation callback from Composable with state changes causing infinite calls on navigation
I have Splash screen (or any other Screen) which is calling API and changing state from Loading to Finished or Failed.
This is my UiModel:
@Immutable
data class SplashUiModel(
    var state: SplashLoadingState = SplashLoadingState.InProgress,
)

sealed interface SplashLoadingState {

    object InProgress: SplashLoadingState

    object Valid: SplashLoadingState

    object Invalid: SplashLoadingState

}

Within my ViewModel I have it like this:
private val _state: MutableStateFlow<SplashUiModel> = MutableStateFlow(SplashUiModel())
val state = _state.asStateFlow()

I made extension function which should just update its value only if new value is different:
inline fun <T> MutableStateFlow<T>.updateIfDifferent(function: (T) -> T) {
    while (true) {
        val prevValue = value
        val nextValue = function(prevValue)

        // Check if the value is actually different before trying to update
        if (prevValue == nextValue) {
            // No need to update if the value hasn't changed
            return
        }

        // Atomically update the value using compareAndSet
        if (compareAndSet(prevValue, nextValue)) {
            return
        }
    }
}

Within API response inside ViewModel I call for example that response was invalid:
_state.updateIfDifferent { it.copy(state = SplashLoadingState.Invalid) }

Within my composable I'm collecting state:
val state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

And then I decide what to do/show:
        when(state.value) {
            SplashLoadingState.Valid -> {
                listener.onNavigateValid()
            }
            SplashLoadingState.Invalid -> {
                listener.onNavigateInvalid()
            }
            SplashLoadingState.InProgress -> {
                BaseLoadingIndicator()
            }
        }

Listener:
 var hasNavigated by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val listener = object : SplashScreenListener {
        override fun onNavigateValid() {
            if (!hasNavigated) {
                hasNavigated = true
                onValid.invoke()
            }
        }

        override fun onNavigateInvalid() {
            if (!hasNavigated) {
                hasNavigated = true
                onInvalid.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

onValid.invoke() and onInvalid.invoke() are callback functions inside SplashScreen composable constructor calling navController.navigate to other screen. I'm using TypeSafe navigation so sometimes those callbacks contains even data which are passed to other screen.
SplashScreen is basic simple example but usually UiModel class contains more stuff like loaded data which are displayed in Composable (Lists, Strings etc) and not just state.
What is happening to me right now is that onValid is called indefinitely if I change state based on API call response. And screen is flickering nonstop. I don't understand why is this a case when I even added hasNavigated flag to trigger this navigation callback just once. Also updateIfDifferent should also prevent updating value if its same (it is not the case most of the time but this API call is one time only when app is started).
I even try to use LaunchedEffect to fire it just once:
when(state.value) {
     SplashLoadingState.Valid -> {
          LaunchedEffect(Unit){
               listener.onNavigateValid()
           }
     }
     SplashLoadingState.Invalid -> {
          LaunchedEffect(Unit){
               listener.onNavigateInvalid()
          }
     }
     SplashLoadingState.InProgress -> {
          BaseLoadingIndicator()
     }
 }

Still same result.
UPDATE:
Okay this sounds crazy but I have other screen which has custom NavTypes passed which are Parcelable type (passing data objects which contains data objects so I had to make custom NavType for it). And even if I do not use it in this callback function, for some reason (maybe its NavGraphBuilder bug or something), it is calling recomposition of every single Screen within my Navigation Graph.
Example:
dialog<ScreenData.RandomScreen>(
        typeMap = mapOf(
            typeOf<ParcelableObject>() to CustomNavTypes.parcelableType<ParcelableObject>(),
            typeOf<ParcelableObject2>() to CustomNavTypes.parcelableType<ParcelableObject2>(),
            typeOf<ParcelableObject3>() to CustomNavTypes.parcelableType<ParcelableObject3>()
        )
    ) {
        RandomScreenComposable(
            viewModel = hiltViewModel(),
        )
    }

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> parcelableType(
        isNullableAllowed: Boolean = false,
        json: Json = Json,
    ) = object : NavType<T>(isNullableAllowed = isNullableAllowed) {
        override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String) =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                bundle.getParcelable(key, T::class.java)
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                bundle.getParcelable(key)
            }

        override fun parseValue(value: String): T = json.decodeFromString(value)

        override fun serializeAsValue(value: T): String = json.encodeToString(value)

        override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: T) = bundle.putParcelable(key, value)
    }

If anybody knows why is this happening, let me know because it seems so random.
If I'm unable to use custom objects within this new TypeSafe navigation, it will make my life difficult since I will be forced to pass simple types such as Strings and Ints only between screens.
When I commented out those NavTypes and removed parcelable data class, it is working fine for my SplashScreen.

If you make your parcelableType object class override equals() and hashCode(), do you see the behavior go away?

Now it works but it crashes when I want to retrieve object from savedStateHandle within ViewModel of Dialog. I've got "Cannot cast payloadItem of type ParcelableObject to NavType."

Does your ViewModel use savedStateHandle.toRoute and pass your same typeMap in? Show your code

Yes. Inside ViewModel I load data like this:
private val data = savedStateHandle.toRoute<ScreenData.RandomScreen>()

Then you weren't passing your typeMap into the toRoute method.
